# PowerShell Forms. How come in my Form Closing event If I can't call a Function or use Write-output, but it works if I use Write-Host

Tags: forms, powershell, formclosing

I have a small form I'm working on but I have something I'm confused about. I have a closing event
`$Form.Add_Closing({})` In there I'm wanting to stop a custom logging module but it doesn't reflect the output to the console, same if I use `write-output`. If I use `Write-Host` though, that reflects to the console. Does the `Closing` event just have any real output capability?

```
$Form.Add_Closing({
# my logging function - doesn't work
Write-Log -Stop

# Write-Output - doesn't work
Write-Output 'Test message'

# Write-Host - does work
Write-Host 'Another Test message'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem applies to *all* events, not just `Closing`:

Inside a PowerShell [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) serving as a .NET event delegate:

- You *can* call arbitrary commands...
- ... but their *success-stream* (pipeline) output is *discarded*.

However, output to any of PowerShell's *other* [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) *does* surface in the caller's console, as you've experienced with [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host).

Therefore, if you simply want to **print the called commands' success output to the caller's *display***, you can pipe them to [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host):

```bash
$Form.Add_Closing({
  Write-Log -Stop | Out-Host
})
```

Note:

- `Out-Host`'s output - unlike `Write-Host`'s - can fundamentally neither be captured nor suppressed.
- Output from `Write-Host`, which since v5 writes via the information stream, can be suppressed with `6>$null`, and *in principle* be captured via the [common `-InformationVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-informationvariable), if your script is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) script and it is invoked with, say, `./yourScript -InformationVariable capturedInfoStream`.
  However, this does *not* work with `Write-Host` calls made *inside event-delegate script blocks*.

---

If you want to ***collect* success output emitted from event-delegate script blocks for *later use in the script*** (which also allows you to control if the collected output is sent to the script's *caller* or not), create a list in the script scope, to which you can append from the event-delegate script blocks:

```bash
# Initialize a list to collect event-delegate output in.
$outputFromEventDelegates = [Collections.Generic.List[object]] @()

# ...

$Form.Add_Closing({
  # Call the function of interest and add its output to the
  # script-scope list.
  $outputFromEventDelegates.AddRange(
    @(Write-Log -Stop)
  )
})

# ... after the .ShowDialog() call

# Now you can access all collected output.
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Output collected from event delegates:"
$outputFromEventDelegates
```